# NoMethodError: undefined method `bytesize' for #<Array:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, heroku

I am trying to call my custom api which uploades file using paperclip , its working fine on local using https://github.com/jwagener/httmultiparty , but when I try to call the api and upload file for heroku deployed app, following errors occurs.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `bytesize' for #<Array:0x00000006e71980>
    from /home/umair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1735:in `send_request_with_body'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1724:in `exec'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1189:in `transport_request'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1177:in `request'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gm/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1170:in `block in request'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in `request'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gm/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gm/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty/request.rb:76:in `perform'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gm/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty/request.rb:208:in `handle_response'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gm/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty/request.rb:90:in `perform'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gm/gems/httparty-0.8.3/lib/httparty.rb:400:in `perform_request'
    from /home/umair/Projects/core/lib/httmultiparty.rb:81:in `post'
    from (irb):5
    from /home/umair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gm/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gm/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/umair/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gm/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

I am running this on ruby console to test the file upload api.

```
HttpClient.post('/storage.xml',:basic_auth=>   {:username=>'badde88248834bec759d94563f102d52e19702fa',:password=>'b890b48e2769192372bf531fc46827cd86bea23f'} ,:query => {:auth_token=> '1045aa26cda23f5f3aec737a45e7ba0017c1a7cf',:user_file => File.new( '/home/umair/Login.png')})
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and couldn't find a solution. Now I'm doing this, it only requires the `multipart-post` gem.

```
class Client
  require 'net/http/post/multipart'

  def self.perform inputurl, file
    url = URI.parse(inputurl)
    File.open(file) do |transfile|
      Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
        req = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new(
          url.path,
          file1: UploadIO.new(transfile, "multipart/formdata", File.basename(file)),
        )
        response = http.request(req)
      end
    end
  end
end
```